# HTML - Submit button does not appear although it is stated

Tags: php, html, mysql

The code does not display the submit which is important for the MySQL statement to be submitted to the MySQL server. I tried to insert the button in between the forms and not in the end. but it is weirdly not working the way I intended it to be displaying.

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <center><b> Volunteer Management </b></center>


    <center>
    <a href="index.php">Add User </a>
    <a href="add_skill.php"> Add Skills </a>
    <a href="assign_user.php">Assign User</a>
    </center>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        $config = parse_ini_file('/config.ini'); 


        $conn = new mysqli($config['servername'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database']);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "SELECT skillName FROM skills";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $num=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $conn->close();
    ?>
    <form method="get">

        Username: <br>
        <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
        Password: <br>
        <input type="text" name="password"> <br>
        Name: <br>
        <input type="text" name="fullname"> <br>
        Title: <br>
        <input type="text" name="title"> <br> <br>

        Permission:

        <select name="permission">
            <option selected disabled>Choose here</option>
            <option value="0">Admin</option>
            <option value="1">Project Manager</option>
            <option value="2">Volunteer</option>
            <option value="6">Accounting Officer</option>
        </select> <br><br>



        Skills: <br>

        <?php

            $i=0;while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $skillName=$row['skillName']; 

        ?>

        <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="<?php echo $skillName; ?>" ><?php echo $skillName; ?><br>

        <?php $i++;} ?>
        <br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit>

    </form>

    <?php

            if(isset($_GET['submit']))
            {
                $config = parse_ini_file('/config.ini'); 


                $conn = new mysqli($config['servername'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database']);

                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 

                 $username = $_GET['username'];
                 $password = $_GET['password'];
                 $fullname = $_GET['fullname'];
                 $title = $_GET['title'];
                 $profil = $_GET['permisssion'];
                 $created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                 $sql = "INSERT INTO members (organization,login,password,name,title,profil,created) VALUES ('1','$username','$password','$fullname','$title','$permission','$created')";
                 $result = $conn->query($sql);
                 $conn->close();
            }
    ?>



</body>
```

Comment: invalid html. no closing `"` in your button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<input type="submit" name="submit>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-check your code.
Since there is no closing " (double quote) after `submit` in `input` tag

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

add the closing 
`</form>` tag and `</html>` tag